# WPF datagrid fill with uneven data to look even

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have an auto generated Datagrid that shows queried data from an API. The results come in array form and i put them in a DataTable, that are shown in Datatgrid. The array length are not always the same and the columns are not "even". 
`|--DTColumn1---DTColumn2-----|
|---Data1----|---Data1-------|
|---Data2----|---Data3-------|
|---Data3----|---Data5-------|
|---Data4----|---emptycell---|
|---Data5----|---emptycell---|`

The "DTColumn" are the arrays that contain the data, that are similar, but parts could be missing and that is not an error. I don't know the data that I will get in runtime, but i know that it will contain some similar data.

Any advice to make it look like this: 
`|--DTColumn1---DTColumn2-----|
|---Data1----|---Data1-------|
|---Data2----|---emptycell---|
|---Data3----|---Data3-------|
|---Data4----|---emptycell---|
|---Data5----|---Data5-------|`

**EDIT:**

Code structure:

```
  private void buttonget_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        sngrid.ItemsSource = null;
        string dtnumber = DTBox.Text;
        if (dtnumber == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("NO DATA!");
        }
        else
        {
            string[] dtresvalues;// this is were the DTColumn's come from and the number a of loop's for the second apicall
            int s = apicall.Check..; //<- check if input can be handled and get dtresvalues
            if (s != 5)
            {
                //API error handling here
            }
            else
            {
            var list = dtresvalues.Where((value, index) => index % 2 == 0).ToArray();// get rid of excess/usles data
            string[] predt = list.ToArray();// prepared data, actual DTColumn's in array
             DataTable table = new DataTable();
             for (int i = 0; i < predt.Length; i++)//loop untill DTColumn run out
             {
             string kerdt = predt[i];// set current DTColumn for API
             int si = apicall.Get...;// if no error, it returns the resoultvalues array (data1, data2,...)
                    if (si != 0)
                    {
                        //API error handling here
                    }
                    else
                    {
                     table.Columns.Add(kerdt);//set column name in table
                     if (i == 0)//this loop down, add's resoultvalues of API to current column of table(data1,data2, ..)
                        {
                            foreach (string sd in resoultvalues)
                            {
                                table.Rows.Add(sd);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            while (table.Rows.Count < resoultvalues.Length)
                            {
                                table.Rows.Add();
                            }
                            for (int j = 0; j < resoultvalues.Length; j++)
                            {
                                table.Rows[j].SetField(i, resoultvalues[j]);
                            }

                        }
                    }

                }
                // add finished table to datagrid
                sngrid.ItemsSource = table.DefaultView;
```

}

Also resoultvalues is an array.

Comment: What do you mean with even? The width of Cells, that the strings are centered or that the values of the right column are alternately ordered?

Comment: By even i don't mean any type of style formatting. I want that if there is a data1 the next column data1 should be next to it, if there is no data2 and no data2 in 2nd column then emptycell, but if the 3rd column has it again then it should be in that row, with the possibility of not having data1.

Comment: If it don't takes too much perfomance/time, why not reordering the arrays after getting them from the source? Or you could event put them in a new llist/array with KeyValuesPairs like `KeyValuePair<DataItem, DataItem>

Comment: The problem would be if i get a 100+ array's back.. This is all runtime generated, so i don't know the number of column's and the assigned row's..

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what type of data is inside `DTColumn1` and `DTColumn2`, but I imagine that there is something to let you know that, for example, `DTColumn1[0]` is relative to `DTColumn2[3]`.

You can create two new arrays and use it as containers for your arrays of data, while filling the new array mind the empty fields.

Example:

```
string[] DTColumn1 = {
    "1-foo",
    "2-bar",
    "3-foobar"
};
string[] DTColumn2 = {
    "1-foo2",
    "3-foobar2"
};


//Find the longest array of the two
string[] longestArray = DTColumn1;
string[] shortestArray = DTColumn2;

if (DTColumn2.Length > longestArray.Length) {
    longestArray = DTColumn2;
    shortestArray = DTColumn1;
}


//Instantiating new lists to show data
List<string> col1 = new List<string>();
List<string> col2 = new List<string>();


//Filling "interface" lists with data
foreach (void value_loopVariable in longestArray) {
    value = value_loopVariable;
    col1.Add(value);
}

//This can be tricky, but I really have no idea of how your data is structured
foreach (void value1_loopVariable in col1) {
    value1 = value1_loopVariable;

    foreach (void value2_loopVariable in shortestArray) {
        value2 = value2_loopVariable;
        if (value1[0].Equals(value2[0])) {
            col2.Add(value2);
            break;
        }

        //When the program reaches this point means that there is no corrispondace of data, so we add an empty value to col2
        col2.Add("");

    }

}
//Here you'll have col1 and col2 filled with data
```

This will result in this:

```
|--DTColumn1---|--DTColumn2-----|
|---1-foo------|---1-foo2-------|
|---2-bar------|---emptycell----|
|---3-foobar---|---3-foobar2----|
```

You may notice that if `DTColumn2` is the longer array it will be placed in the first column of the table.

I wrote down a raw example just to give you an idea, please note that this is untested code

Comment: Why you are posting VB Code when his question is tagged with C#?

Comment: My fault, I was inattentive. Edited the answer

Comment: Edited and added the structure. the problem with this if the DTcolumn is from 1 to 50.

Comment: Please simplify your edit. The whole code is confusing, I suggest to clearly indicate what is your input data (we have no idea how the API works) by showing some example data like I did in my example.

Comment: Added more description to the code. The API work method is unnecessary , because its not part of the problem. The API gives out the array/array's and its out of scope from there.

Comment: I am confident that the API should give you something to let you know what values are coupled. Although it is a very strange way to get a table. I would espect to make a single call to get all the data, it doesn't make sense to make a call for each column. Has the API got any documentation/examples?

Comment: The problem is that the API wont let me other options then to recall  it as many times as necessary. To give an example of the working method: you target a folder(as input), u check for txt files and get the names as DTcolumn's. Then start reading the first file, get the first line (data1), read next line(data2), until end of file and put data in row's for the current column in DatatTable. Repeat until no more files and add DataTable to Datagrid.

Comment: Do you have any API documentation? It can be very hacky this way. How do you decide when to leave an empty cell in a column and when not? Maybe you should restart with a different algorithm

Comment: I have an API documentation, but it doesn't show any other options, even the UI they provided is crap. If you want to know some details about colors, you have to ask for the colors, then have to re-ask the specific color to get details. This is what I want to simplify for end users, with this grid.

Comment: Maybe you should give up with this API, have you searched for alternatives? Have you considered implementing it yourself?